# How to Handle repeated calendar event in android

Tags: android

I want to handle repeated **Google calender events** for changing phone mode to silent/general . Normal one time events are work properly but in the case of **repeated events** i can't get the **ending date and time**. Only get an predefined Ending time(Thu, 1 Jan 5:30:00 IST 1970). How to over come this problem.?

Answer (score 0):

In CalendarContract, it is defined that for recurring event DTEND(end time) is null, but DURATION is defined.
Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html